# Problems with Clipboard managers and Office365

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, office365, clipboard

On a windows10 with Office365, I can't paste values from Clipboard recorder or the opensource Ditto clipboard.

Same behavior in excel or Word, the combination keys are recognized by clipboard app, window popup is displayed, I can select a value from the list but nothing is pasted in office app.

In other apps or Libreoffice, clipboard manager work fine. Unfortunately Office 365 is the default corporative app, so I can't go to a previous version or replace by Libreoffice.

any ideas?